# How optimize BK-Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, cython, bk-tree

I'm  implementing a BK-Tree in Cython.

For one million items, the search time is too long! It's ~30 seconds :(

Here is my Cython code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from itertools import imap
from PIL import Image

DEF MAX_TREE_POOL = 10000

cdef extern from "distances.h":
    int hamming_distance(char *a, char *b)
    enum: HASH_BITS


cdef findInTree(Node parent, Item item, int threshold):
        cdef int d
        cdef int i = 0

        cdef Node child

        cdef object childrens
        cdef object results = []
        cdef object extends = results.extend

        if parent:
            d = hamming_distance(item.hash, parent.item.hash)
            childrens = parent.childrens.get

            if d <= threshold:
                results.append((d, parent.item))

            for i in xrange(max(0, d - threshold), d + threshold + 1):
                child = childrens(i)
                if child:
                    extends(findInTree(child, item, threshold))

        return results


cdef class Item:

    cdef public unsigned int id
    cdef public object hash

    def __init__(Item self, unsigned int id, object hash):
        assert id > 0 and len(hash) == HASH_BITS

        self.id = id
        self.hash = hash

    def __str__(Item self):
        return '<Item {0}>'.format(self.id)

    def __repr__(Item self):
        return '<Item #{0} object at 0x{1}>'.format(self.id, id(self))


cdef class Node:

    cdef readonly Item item
    cdef readonly dict childrens

    def __cinit__(Node self, Item item):
        self.item = item
        self.childrens = {}

    def __repr__(Item self):
        return '<Node object at 0x{0} item {1} childrens {2}>'.format(id(self), repr(self.item), repr(self.childrens))


cdef class BKTree:

    cdef readonly Node tree
    cdef readonly unsigned int count

    def __cinit__(BKTree self):
        self.count = 0

    def addItem(BKTree self, Item item):
        cdef int w
        cdef int d

        cdef object a

        cdef Node n
        cdef Node c

        if not self.tree:
            self.tree = Node(item)
        else:
            w = 1
            c = self.tree

            a = item.hash

            while w:
                d = hamming_distance(a, c.item.hash)
                n = c.childrens.get(d)

                if n is None:
                    c.childrens[d] = Node(item)

                    # Break
                    w = 0
                else:
                    c = c.childrens[d]

        self.count += 1

        # Success, return
        return self.count

    def query(BKTree self, Item item, int threshold):
        return findInTree(self.tree, item, threshold)


cdef class BKTreePool:

    cdef list pool
    cdef readonly unsigned int count
    cdef BKTree tree

    def __cinit__(BKTreePool self):
        self.pool = []
        self.rotate()

    def addItem(BKTreePool self, Item item):
        if self.tree.count >= MAX_TREE_POOL:
            self.rotate()

        try:
            self.tree.addItem(item)
            self.count += 1
        finally:
            return self.count

    def query(BKTreePool self, Item item, int threshold):
        cdef BKTree tree
        cdef list results

        results = []

        for tree in self.pool:
            results.extend(tree.query(item, threshold))

        return results


    cdef rotate(BKTreePool self):
        self.pool.append(BKTree())
        self.tree = self.pool[-1]
```

distances.h

```
#ifndef DISTANCES_H

  #define DISTANCES_H 1
  #define HASH_BITS 16 * 16

  static int hamming_distance(char *a, char *b);
  // static int default_distance(char *a, char *b);

  static int hamming_distance(char *a, char *b) {
      unsigned int distance = 0;
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i <= HASH_BITS; i++) {
          if (a[i] != b[i]) {
              distance++;
          }
      }

      return distance;
  }

#endif
```

Example:

```
tree = BKTreePool()
tree.addItem(Item(1, '10' * 256))
tree.addItem(Item(1, '10' * 256))
....

tree.query(Item(1, '10' * 256), 5)
```

This tree begins search duplicate images by 256 bits hash.

How can I optimize this `findInTree` function?

Comment: One thing I can think of is not to call `findInTree` recursively but use an iterative search instead, it's usually much faster. Also, implementing this in C will probably be still much faster than Cython. But the whole idea seems a bit strange to me, I have to say. calculating hamming distance on a 256 byte string is expensive.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Yes. I was thinking about recursion, i cannot implement it without recursion, maybe small example? Why is 256 bit for Hamming is bad? Function hamming_distace call very fast.

Comment: Ummm `'10'` * 256 is a string of length 512 BYTES and you are calling it a 256-bit "hash"???

Comment: Also one million * 512 bytes is 0.5 Gb just for your hashes. Add in your tree structure and you may be swapping out of real memory; have you checked for this?

Comment: Tangentially, how are you generating your hashes? Are you sure it exhibits the sort of locality you need to work with? And note that BK-Tree search will be inefficient for larger distances, as it has to search more of the tree.

Comment: @John Machin Sorry, this wrong example. Just '10' * 128.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Hash generated from image pixels (image 16x16). Yes, i have larger distances (1-256). What can be replaced BK-Tree?

Comment: @p0is0n What distances are you typically searching on? You might want to look into better known computer vision algorithms; I suspect this one isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Nick Johnson First distance 1-2 for check duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a lot of memory (and thus swapping and/or cache flushing) by representing your "256-bit hash" in 256 bits (32 bytes) instead of 256 or 512 bytes.

Python pseudocode:

```
num_bits_set = (0, 1, 1, 2, 1, etc etc, 7, 8)
assert len(num_bits_set) == 256

def ham_diff(a, b):
    h = 0
    for p, q in zip(a, b):
        h += num_bits_set[ord(p) ^ ord(q)]
    return h
```